# IDuplexSessionChannel BeginSend not sending during high UI thread tasks

Tags: silverlight-4.0

We have a Silverlight 4 application utilizing an IDuplexSessionChannel to send data to/from the application to a WCF service.

I've noticed that during very high UI thread usage (such as application startup when the UI is building itself) calls to our WCF service via IDuplexSessionChannel.BeginSend are not sent until the UI has completed rendering.

The calls to BeginSend are being done within a BackgroundWorker.
Does the actual execution of BeginSend occur on the main thread? I couldn't find anything "official" that documents this.
It would seem so since even if I have the main thread Sleep or WaitOne the messages still do not go through (note this was just a test).

What would be the best way to get those calls to go out immediately?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/WCF-asynchrony-pitfall.aspx  

Somebody blogged this today. Explains exactly what I've seen with the WCF calls not going out while we're heavily processing on the UI thread.  

WCF calls in Silverlight are marshaled through the UI thread.  

Why does Silverlight go through the trouble of forcing all WCF calls to be asynchronous in order to keep the UI responsive, yet marshal all the WCF calls through the UI thread????  

Doesn't make sense to me.